# How can I group a set of days into weeks with the date as the name of the row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

In a pandas DataFrame, I have a table of dates. They range from January 5th 2019 to today and there is a date for each consecutive day. I would like to group these into weeks, from the previous Friday to Friday and then have the name of that grouped week be the date of that Friday.

For example:

```
2019-01-08
2019-01-09
2019-01-10
2019-01-11
2019-01-12
2019-01-13
2019-01-14
2019-01-15
```

get grouped up as week of 2019-01-15

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see (https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-week-number-from-a-date-in-python) for isocalendar

```
from datetime import date
dates=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end=date.today())
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Week']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
print(df)
```